# Getting Null on Autowired Class when calling from other class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Test.java

```
@Service
public class Test {

public void Testing() {
    System.out.println("inside testing");
}
}
```

here is my factory class

```
@Service
 public class ClaimFactory extends BaseClaimFactory {

   @Autowired
   ClaimProvider claimProvider;

@Override
public ClaimProvider getClaimRequest( String type) throws Exception {

    if (type.equals(ClaimProviderEnums.ABC.toString())) {

         claimProvider = new ABCIMP();
    }

    return claimProvider;
}

}
```

Here is my ABCIMP.java class

```
@Service
public class ABCIMP implements ClaimProvider {

@Autowired
Test test;

public void claimRequest(){
      test.testing();
   }
```

}

i calling like this

```
     claimProviders=baseClaimFactory.getClaimRequest();
     claimProviders.claimRequest();
```

i dono why i get java.lang.NullPointerException on line `test.testing()` does anybody know why this is happing  and it is working when i call 
   `aBCIMP.claimRequest()`

Comment: Isnt `ABCIMP` a `Component`, not a `Service`.  I would ask the same question for your `Test` class as well.

Comment: coz its a Service layer ABCIMP.java. ..even with component is not working

Comment: Yes, it won't work when you dont let the IOC container take care of proxying the objects for you.  You cannot do `new X()` and expect Spring to manage that for you.

Comment: When i return `Autowire ABCIMP aBCIMP;` and return it like  `return aBCIMP ` in getClaimRequest and  then i get null pointer at  `  claimProviders.claimRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

You have created `ABCIMP` instance with `new ABCIMP();`. Spring Framework won't process objects created with Java `new` operator unless you have configured AspectJ Proxies.

Do not create new instance, use only `@Autowired` to obtain existing instance from Spring context. Remove the `ClaimFactory` class completely, you are repeating Spring's work. If you need to get the instance in the runtime:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

...

if (type.equals(ClaimProviderEnums.ABC.toString())) {
     return ctx.getBean(ABCIMP.class);
}
```

Comment: so in place of `claimProvider = new ABCIMP()` what should i use

Comment: @GauravSingh read about the Spring auto-wiring and learn how it works: by-type, by-name, or with other classifiers. `ClaimFactory` seems not needed in your example, Spring DI is the factory for all beans.

Comment: when returnin like `return ctx.getBean(ABCIMP.class);` i get null pointer at  same line